# Нужна помощь с паркингом из vk (не api)

Tags: c#, html5, парсер, вконтакте

Мне нужно получить все id страниц пользователе с заданным именем и фамилией.Однако Vk api выдает только первые 1000 страниц
Условно, если "Павел Дуров" зарегистрировано 10000, то он возьмет первую 1000 вычтет удаленных и заблокированных и выдаст 600.

Но при [ссылочном запросе](https://vk.com/search?c%5Bper_page%5D=40&c%5Bq%5D=40&c%5Bq%5D=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%94%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2&c%5Bsection%5D=people) на сайт выдается весь стек с пост загрузкой по offset.

**Нужный фрагмент HTML:**

```
 <div class="results blt_cont bl_cont mark_top_verified ">

    <a href="/durov" class="simple_fit_item search_item">
        <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836333/v836333001/31193/dNxZpRF-z_M.jpg?ava=1" class="si_img" />
        <div class="si_body">
        <span class="si_owner">РџР°РІРµР» Р”СѓСЂРѕРІ<b class="verified"></b></span>
        <div class="si_slabel">РЎРџР±Р“РЈ '06</div><div class="si_slabel">34 РіРѕРґР°, РЎР°РЅРєС‚-РџРµС‚РµСЂР±СѓСЂРі</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    ///////
    <a href="/id274583833" class="simple_fit_item search_item">
        <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c624828/v624828833/6657/4KQkPXYe224.jpg?ava=1" class="si_img" />
         <div class="si_body">
         <span class="si_owner">РџР°РІРµР» Р”СѓСЂРѕРІ</span>
         <div class="si_slabel">РЎР°РЅРєС‚-РџРµС‚РµСЂР±СѓСЂРі, Р РѕСЃСЃРёСЏ</div><div class="si_slabel">23 РіРѕРґР°</div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Прошу помочь с там, как вытаскивать

- `/durov` из `<a href="/durov"`
- `/id274583833` из `<a href="/id274583833"`

Решение не важно, важен результат
Сам пробовал и AngelSharp, и Html Agility pack  для меня проблема что нет `id`.

Comment: А зачем вам `id`? Мыслите шире! Допустим где у вас элемент `<a href="/durov"`? А он находится в `<div class="labeled name">`. Или где у вас `<a href="/id274583833"`?  А все там же в `<div class="labeled name">`. Так что вам мешает выбрать этот labeled name и из него выбрать первый href? Допустим так: `.SelectNodes("//div[@class='labeled name']/a")?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetAttributeValue("href", null);`

Comment: Я б не заморачивался и достал нужное по регулярке `<a href="/(\w+)"`. PS: Вредные советы по парсингу сайтов регулярками.

Comment: У тебя кодировка неправильная. И вообще, эта разметка вообще не похожа на ту, которую мне отдаёт vk.

Comment: Прошу прощения, эта волшебная машина, дает разный ответ для зарегистрированных пользователей и простых запросов, сейчас правильный фрагмент

Answer (score 1):

Парсить html - последнее дело... 
Попробую вам подсказать...

Вы правы, что vk выдает лишь 1000 по API. 
Но ключевое - это лимит на фильтр. Т.е. если вы разобьете ваши запросы на, скажем, пол, возраст (до месяца), гео признак, то перебор даст вам возможность использовать api.

Comment: В api точно нет параметра `offset`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть, но работает по все той же 1000. т.е. можно перебирать по 200 шт за раз, например

Comment: Мы пытались, это дает прирост 3% к  простому запросу `coun=999`  `offset=0`, и приводит к временной блокировке запроса (через n попыток, простой `coun=999`  `offset=0` запрос 
 и все другие вариации возвращают 0 страниц)

Comment: @ВладиславЛис, соблюдая лимиты и через  юзер-токен  такого быть не должно. попробуйте бить по дате рождения.. (по секрету: даже если пользователь спрятал ее в профайле - фильтр все равно работает.. вплоть до дня ;) )

Comment: @ morphey83 Вот это мы и побывали, но "Обратите внимание — даже при использовании параметра offset для получения информации доступны только первые 1000 результатов.", дошли уже до таких парсерных костылей